# count items in col as rows MYSQL

Tags: mysql, matrix, count

Dear developers and programmers,

I have a tabel with SHOP_ID, PROD_ID, ipadres and some more tables, but these are where its all about...

Looks like this:

```
id ip number        timestamp   shop_id prod_id
--------------------------------------------------
42  81.69.205.25    1319488326  2       3   
43  81.205.141.48   1319492649  2       3   
44  193.58.10.10    1319520579  14      17  
45  84.28.22.226    1319529529  11      19  
46  88.15.81.188    1319543745  2       1   
47  178.17.241.191  1319563031  14      7   
48  87.28.107.171   1319563038  2       6   
49  80.156.47.144   1319572818  14      7   
50  82.76.241.175   1319577506  11      1   
51  82.76.241.175   1319577584  13      1   
52  82.76.241.175   1319577785  14      1   
53  82.76.241.175   1319577860  4       1   
54  62.94.133.153   1319579221  14      1   
55  62.94.133.153   1319579281  2       3   
56  77.70.175.221   1319617238  11      1   
57  77.70.175.221   1319621845  13      1   
58  77.70.175.221   1319621848  2       1   
59  77.70.175.221   1319621850  11      1 
.... more
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to see for each prod_id how many ip numbers there excist for each shop id?

output example

```
        1        2        3        4        5
---------------------------------------------
1       18       5        51       8        4
2       58       5        45       3        4
3       7        6        31       9        2
```

where horizontal is the prod_id and vertical is the shop_id

I've don this already:

```
select 

shop_id,
count(distinct(ipadres)) amount

from table

GROUP BY    shop_id

order by amount desc
```

but this wil give me only the result of all prod_id's combined.

I would like to have the prod_id's seperate in columns.

I hope there is a solution!

Kind Regards

Comment: take a look a pivot clause. I think it will help you. And example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select `prod_id`,shop_id,
    count(distinct(ipadres)) amount        
    from table        
    GROUP BY shop_id,prod_id        
    order by amount desc
```